# Nested listviews scrolling behavior different when scrolled using drag vs scrollwheel

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter web.
When we scroll by dragging the mouse, parent scrolls even when child listview is under cursor. But while scrolling with mouse wheel or double finger swipe gesture on touchpads, the scroll behavior is different. The parent stops scrolling and child starts scrolling when child listview comes under cursor.
[gif of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poZLV.gif)
You can try the following code.

```
var _container = Container(
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.blue,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ListView")),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: ListView( // parent ListView
        children: <Widget>[
          _container,
          _container,
          Container(
            height: 200, // give it a fixed height constraint
            color: Colors.teal,
            // child ListView
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item ${i}"))),
          ),
          _container,
          _container,
          _container,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

What I want is for the mousewheel scroll to behave like dragging. How can I get that?

Comment: have you found a solution?